# Grub loader problem

Tags: 11.04, boot, grub2, windows-xp

I recently updated my Wubi install form 10.10 to 11.04.
This had problems, so I finally took the plunge and gave Ubuntu its own partition.
It all seemed to go very well (I even got a purple bootscreen which was very exciting the first time).

However, whenever I try to enter Windows XP, I get a flashing horizontal line for a second.
Then it disappears, and I return back to Grub.

Is there a way to get GRUB to load Windows XP?
What additional information if any is required?

Comment: **Welcome to AskUbuntu!** Please make sure you put a **blank line** between paragraphs. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

by the way, you should put (#) in the begining of the line , not in front of the line as you said.

---

anyway....

you have to install ubuntu on its own partition alongside windows or delete windows OS. and install ubuntu on the first partiton (sda1).

but before to do anything, backup your data & make sure to check your hard disk and do defragment for all the harddisk partitions :[read this](http://windows.about.com/od/maintainandfix/ss/defragment.htm)

---

first, you need to fix the MBR with a bootable winxp CD to restore winxp OS.
boot off a WINXP-CD and when the menu loads, press "R" to go to a command prompt,  Once there, choose which partition you want (usually is 1), and enter an admin password (if any).

and then run these commands :

> fixboot
>   fixmbr
>   exit

after that we need to restore ubuntu boot-loader too:

01 - boot off your Ubuntu-LiveCD (try without install)

02 - open Terminal type:

> sudo -i

03 - then type:

> fdisk -l

04 - if you have just one harddisk on your PC you will got something like this,  ex; on an old PC:

> fdisk -l
>   Disk /dev/sda: 40.0 GB, 80026361856 bytes
>   255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 9729 cylinders
>   Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
>   Disk identifier: 0xf6edf6ed
>   Device Boot  Start  End  Blocks  Id  System
>   /dev/sda1  *  1 1217  9775521  7  HPFS/NTFS
>   /dev/sda2  1218  4866  29306401  f  W95 Ext’d (LBA)
>   /dev/sda5  1218  2434  9775521  7  HPFS/NTFS
>   /dev/sda6  2435  3650  9765888 b  W95 FAT32
>   /dev/sda7  365  3772 972800  82  Linux swap / Solaris
>   /dev/sda8 3772  4866  8786944  83  Linux

05 - mount ubuntu partition:

> mount /dev/sda8 /mnt

06 - install grub2 on MBR section in 'sda' (the best place) **do not install it on the partiton. ex: 'sda1'**:

> grub-install --root-directory=/mnt/ /dev/sda

07 - if no errors appear that means everything is OK :

> reboot

08 - return to ubuntu OS & open Terminal and type:

> sudo update-grub

now, Ubuntu sure recognise windows OS and add it to grub menu

that's all

:-)

---

PS: my english isn't good , if I made a mistake , please correct it .

Answer (score 0):

According to this post: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1195275 The GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET is not working right.
do a :

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

and take a look at this setting:

GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT

**Edit:** Make sure that the following is not commented out and is true.

```
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET = true
```

Comment: thanks for your response @capdragon. what value should this contain?

Comment: Check my edit... i meant (GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET) make sure it's not commented out and is true. see if that works.

Comment: it is already set to true. What now?

Comment: If it's set to true and it's not commented out (has '#' in front of it) then this is not your answer.

Comment: unfortunately no such luck the # out the front seemed to make no difference. would re-imaging the laptop, so it just had XP and then partitioning again fix the problem?

Comment: Tell you the truth i've always had similar problems trying to install linux and windows on the same hard drive. Except on MACs, because i'm able to use rEFIt which works awesome even on triple boot. Makes it VERY easy. If you do start over, get windows 7, and look over this: http://lifehacker.com/5403100/dual+boot-windows-7-and-ubuntu-in-perfect-harmony